# Duda programa con estructuras

Tags: c++

El código funciona bien, pero no sé como puedo hacer para que al llamar a la función de '`pedirdatos`' e introducir todo, vuelva a la función de pantalla principal, mostrándome la posibilidad de introducir otro contacto o visitar los contatos.
Al intentarlo con esta aclaración `-> // pant_principal(n+1);` , no me deja escribir la opción que quiero, se cierra directamente.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct contacto {
  char nombre[30];
  char apellido[30];
  char numtelf[11]; 
} cont[100];


int pant_principal(int n);

void pedirdatos(int n) {
  cout<<"digame el nombre del contacto -> "; 
  cin.getline(cont[n].nombre,30,'\n');
  cin.ignore();
  cout<<"digame el apellido del contacto -> "; 
  cin.getline(cont[n].apellido,30,'\n');
  cin.ignore();
  cout<<"digame el numero del contacto -> "; 
  cin.getline(cont[n].numtelf,11); cin.ignore();

  // pant_principal(n+1);       
}

void mostrardatos(contacto cont[], int n){  
  cout<<"======================================================"<<endl;
  cout<<"                      CONTACTOS"<<endl;
  cout<<"======================================================"<<endl;

  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Nombre: "<<cont[n].nombre<<endl;
  cout<<"Apellido: "<<cont[n].apellido<<endl;
  cout<<"Numero de Telefono: "<<cont[n].numtelf<<endl;
}

int main() {
  int n=0;
  n=pant_principal(n);

  return 0;
}

int pant_principal( int n){     
  int eleccion;

  cout<<"======================================================"<<endl;
  cout<<"                BIENVENIDO A TU AGENDA"<<endl;
  cout<<"======================================================"<<endl;
  cout<<endl;

  cout<<"[1] - visitar agenda"<<endl;
  cout<<"[2] - agregar contacto"<<endl;
  cin>>eleccion;

  switch(eleccion){
  case 1:
    mostrardatos(cont,n);
    break;

  case 2: pedirdatos(n);
    n+=1;
    break;

  default: break;
  }

  return n; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para estas cosas, estan las estructuras de control: `while( ) { }`, `do { } while( )`, `for( ) { }`, y, en caso de necesidad, `goto`.

En el caso que expones, se me ocurre modificar `pant_principal( )` para que, si la opción es desconocida, devuelva `-1`:

```
switch( ) {
...
default:
  n = -1;
  break;
}
```

y modificar `main( )`:

```
int main( ) {
  int n = 0;

  do {
    n = pant_principal( n );
  } while( n != -1 );

  return 0;
}
```

Con lo anterior, debería de *re-llamar* a `pant_principal( )` hasta que ésta devuelva `-1`, cosa que ocurrirá cuando el usuario introduzca una opción distinta de `1` y `2`.

Comment: Goto nunca es una opción salvo que estés trabajando en procesos donde el tiempo sea tan crítico que se justifique su uso 

Answer (score -2):

Se que a la gente no le gusta esta opción porque no es muy práctico, pero para este caso, y remarco ESTE CASO, yo suelo utilizar la funcion goto. De tal forma que cuando acabes, el goto te lleve de nuevo al principio. Pero eso sí, solo para este tipo de casos en los que solo vayas a volver al principio para el menú.